# Why can't I have more than one bounty at once?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't a user have simultaneous bounties any more?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more)

I don't understand the logic behind restricting to one bounty at a time.  Can someone please explain the down side of having multiple bounties at a time being supported?

Comment: You can find your logic over at [Why can't a user have simultaneous bounties any more?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more). You can also look up additional research done towards increasing the amount over [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/can-the-limit-on-simultaneous-bounties-be-relaxed).

Comment: I've made a note to myself to update the graph in the 2nd question when the next data dump is released.