# Remove restriction of only one bounty per user at a time

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the limit on simultaneous bounties be relaxed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/can-the-limit-on-simultaneous-bounties-be-relaxed)

I think it is unreasonable to limit users to only one bounty at a time.  Why is there an arbitrary limit of N=1?

Comment: If you want to know why, the answers are [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more) - it basically boils down to both the fact that bounty access was vastly opened from the original system, and that it simply hasn't changed since that time. If you want to request that it be relaxed, you want to see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more).

Comment: @Grace Thanks  (those links point to the same place.)  Definitely should be relaxed.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The second one was supposed to be [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/can-the-limit-on-simultaneous-bounties-be-relaxed). Still by the same user, as it were. Clipboard must've haywired.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Jeff says:

> Would require major schema changes, so
>   unlikely.
>
> Also, not fielding a lot of actual,
>   real world "wow, if I could just have
>   one more bounty!" requests, other than
>   this.. rather hypothetical.. one.

Which contradicts his other answer in June, 2010

> I'd rather make decisions based on
>   data (actual user behavior) than
>   predictions (the way I guess users
>   might behave). If, after a month or
>   so, it looks safe to increase that
>   limit to 2 or maybe even 3, we can
>   revisit it then.

It seems reasonable (At the very least) to give it a trial.  There is no valid reason against it.