# Are concurrent bounties prohibited?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
>   [Why can't a user have simultaneous bounties any more?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more)

I wanted to offer a bounty on [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857517/error-updating-parent-child-relationship-using-hibernate-jpa), but I can't. Is this because I already have an outstanding bounty on another question?

### Update

It has been confirmed that only one bounty at-a-time is allowed. My next question is why?

Comment: **[Yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)**, you can only have one active bounty at a time.

Comment: Answer to next question: [Why can't a user have simultaneous bounties any more?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more), [Can the limit on simultaneous bounties be relaxed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/can-the-limit-on-simultaneous-bounties-be-relaxed)

Comment: [According to Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/54343#54343), this is a temporary state of affairs. Of course, that was over a year ago. Maybe you could ask him if there are enough data for a policy change now.

Answer (score 3):

From the FAQ:

> There can only be **1 active bounty** per question and per user at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from [the bounty faq](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), "You can only have one open bounty at any one time."