# FAQ still says "one open bounty at any time"

Tags: bug, status-completed, faq-update-request

I've only just noticed that we're allowed 3 simultaneous bounties (great!) and this is in line with the decision mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/can-the-limit-on-simultaneous-bounties-be-relaxed/106887#106887).

[image: I can haz three booties]

However, this change has not found its way into in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties):

[image: FAQ snippet on bounty]

or the ["How does the bounty system work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/134327) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page:

[image: bounty on MSO FAQ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [bounty privilege wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) will be updated in the next build, the meta question/FAQ [was just updated as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/16067/revisions).

Comment: I just edited the privilege wiki.

Comment: @Popular - The *default* wiki to push across all sites (a markdown file used as the base) is what's needing an update here...that'll be pushed in the next deploy.

Comment: Huh, I thought the MSO version was still the master. Thanks!