# Why is "start bounty" sometimes not visible?

Tags: support, bounties

I'd like to start a bounty on [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889428/future-of-gdiplus-windows-user-interfaces-which-will-be-the-replacement) and on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880593/suggestions-for-caching-a-dataset), but I don't see the start bounty link there, despite seeing it on other questions. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a bounty set on one of your questions: [Is there a free (or very cheap) tool for highlighting changes in data for sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206404/is-there-a-free-or-very-cheap-tool-for-highlighting-changes-in-data-for-sql-se)

The rules, [as stated in the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), is that a user may only have one active bounty at a time.

Comment: Hm, then his claim that he can see the "Start bounty" link in other questions must be incorrect. +1

Comment: My guess is that, as he placed his bounty recently, he sees bounty links on cached question or already opened, which weren't refresh since he started his bounty.

Comment: @Eldros you are right.

Comment: @Yy Jiang thanks for the correct answer anyway I do not understand why one cannot have more bounties, I can understand a limit of 3, or of 5, but not 1. I will make another question as a suggestion.

Comment: Mmh... It has already been asked. So I will reply here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more

Answer (score 1):

The question has probably already had a bounty, which expired unawarded because no answer had a score of 2 upvotes or more.

Sadly, for those questions it is not possible to award a new bounty for some reason; under the old system, it was not even possible to accept them any more. They will remain unaccepted forever, which in my eyes is a bug.

Comment: Actually, neither question linked had a bounty at any point. You can check out the bounty history by looking at the question's revision history now.