# User-->Active bounties shows multiple bounties

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, profile-page, active-bounties

#### Given:

- You can only have one active bounty at a time.
- You can post multiple bounties to one question, sequentially.

#### Process:

- Post bounty to a specific question
- Award that bounty
- Post another bounty to that same question
- Visit your active bounties tab ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis?tab=bounties#bpage_1-bsort_active in my case, and is exhibit 1, also captured in a screenshot below since it won't appear this way once I award the bounty)

#### Problem:

Note that you have 2 active bounties - the one which really is active, and the one you previously awarded and is not active.  The screenshot below demonstrates this for 1 active bounty and 4 prior awarded bounties posted on the same question.

[image: Screen shot showing 5 active bounties]

[image: MEME: AWARD ALL THE BOUNTIES!]

Comment: +1 for the HaaH comic panel.  OK, also for the bug, but you get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the next build, since you can only have one bounty active at a time, we'll show *only* the latest on that question...which is the correct data on that tab.

Answer (score 3):

This bug seems to have returned when [multiple simultaneous bounties were enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813).

[image]

#### Update

The duplicates were removed from the list, but are still included in the total value of active bounties:

[image]

Comment: Yep, as a result of those changes this again needs a query change - it will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: @NickCraver: I've updated my post; there's still a related bug on that page.

Comment: @Jeremy try again tomorrow ... I fixed the queries up