# Offered Bounties shows two active bounties on the same question

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, profile-page, active-bounties

I've offered two 500-rep bounties on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer). After the first had ended and while the second was going, [my offered bounties page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/154510/matthew-read?tab=bounties&page=1&bsort=offered) showed that both were active ("ends in 2 days"):

[image: screenshot]

(Also, "grace period".  Get it?  Grace?  Get it?)

It seems related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101763/user-active-bounties-shows-multiple-bounties), but that was for the Active tab and was fixed.

Comment: Damn, you don't play when it comes to offering up points on a bounty.

Comment: @Won't_: I am repeating same sentence twice a day

Comment: I noticed that yesterday and was going to report it.

Comment: I, for one, don't get it.

Comment: @John It's on Grace's question.  Bad, I know.

Comment: Ah ok. I had a feeling it he something to do with Grace, but I'm on a phone so it's a small picture and I didn't notice that. (FWIW, I'd have tried to put a joke there too had I noticed.  :P )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build...we needed some additional love to handle this...it'll only show the indicator on the bounty section *actually* active on that post now.